# Automate app local notification by manipulating the request and response

Tags: android, automation, appium, charles-proxy

I am looking for ways to basically manipulate data that is shown in my app by intercepting the API calls it makes and then basically manipulate the data ( positive and negative scenarios) and then observe how my App behaves. I have been manually intercepting these calls and doing it in Charles Proxy tool but I want to get rid of it and looking for a way to do this through Automation. Set up my test data intercept the API calls through a proxy and then run my functional tests on the App. I am looking to do this for both Android and IPhone Apps.

Note: I have been using Appium for Automation.

Answer (score 0):

Appium is a black-box test automation tool, it has no API to manipulate with application on server side. On Android, it allows you to start Activity/Fragment with pre-defined state, but it is not equal to what you are doing.

I think the right way here is to mock your server, there are multiple libraries, [one example](https://medium.com/@giorgos.neokleous93/mock-responses-with-okhttp-retrofit-f77bf81f9b84).

Then you can make a build for Android/iOS apps to use your mocked server instead of real server. In this case you will pre-define response instead of overriding it with proxy.

Answer (score -1):

You can ask your developer to log the things you want to intercept or if they are already being intercepted in logs.You just need to collect the logs from ADB and use that in your appium code.
You can get the adb logs using :

```
List<LogEntry> logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get("logcat").getAll();
    for(LogEntry entries:logEntries){
        if(entries.getMessage().contains("*Things you need from logs*")){
             entry= entries.getMessage();
        }
    }
return entry;
```